# Can't get bluetooth Adapter in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, forceclose

I was trying to implement the bluetooth chat example given in the android samples. 
I am running it on a jelly beans device which has Android 4.1 version running on it .

The application simply force closes. A part of launcher activity code of launcher activity goes like this.

**WHEN I COMMENT THE LINE "mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();" THE APPLICATION DOES NOT FORCE CLOSE.  and all the toast messages are also displayed which are not with the line uncommented**

```
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
// Member object for the chat services
private BluetoothChatService mChatService = null;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"BluetothChat oncreate()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+++ ON CREATE +++");

    // Set up the window layout
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Get local Bluetooth adapter
  try {     

    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

   //}
    // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }     
 } catch (Exception e) {
       Toast.makeText(this,e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

 }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {



    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"BluetothChat onstart()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onStart();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "++ ON START ++");

    // If BT is not on, request that it be enabled.
    // setupChat() will then be called during onActivityResult
    try {
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            // Otherwise, setup the chat session
        } else {
            if (mChatService == null) {
                setupChat();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
     Toast.makeText(this,e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    }


}
```

Comment: Did you debug your code? Which toast messages are shown if `mBluetoothAdapter` is `null`?

Comment: @matt oncreate(), onstart() and onresume() are shown. and nothing after that.

Comment: If I read your question right (and I am not that sure that I do) you state that your activity is not finished if `mBluetoothAdapter == null`?

Comment: yeah .. it is the case when the bluetooth is not enabled and indeed the toast messsage "Bluetooth is not enabled" comes, and the activity is finished if bluetooth is switched off . * (and mBlueToothadapter is null).

Comment: @MattHandy I did not understand your editing well, maybe just because I am a newbie. Do you just want to say that indentation is important ?

Comment: Indentation by four spaces formats the line as source code. Some of your lines weren't indented so they appeared as plain text.

Comment: @MattHandy okay! what could we do next to solve the problem ?